# Adding a new WindowListener to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, joptionpane, windowlistener

```
    mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(mainFrame, "Are you sure you want to quit?", "Confirm exit.", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, 0, new ImageIcon("")) != 0) {
                return;
            }
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        @Override 
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {}

        @Override 
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}

        @Override 
        public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {}

        @Override 
        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {}

        @Override 
        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {}

        @Override 
        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {}

    });
```

There is my code, is it possible since I only use the windowClosing method to remove all the other in my case, useless methods so it takes less space?

Example

```
    mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(mainFrame, "Are you sure you want to quit?", "Confirm exit.", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, 0, new ImageIcon("")) != 0) {
                return;
            }
            System.exit(-1);
        }

    });
```

Is it possible?

Comment: your `showConfirmDialog` method has too many arguments

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a default implementation of `WindowListener` called [`WindowAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html) which allows you to override the methods you really want to use

Comment: This is also true for other listeners like `MouseListener`/`MouseAdapter`, `MouseMotionListener`/`MouseMotionAdapter`, `KeyListener`/`KeyAdapter` etc..